# Height of div using jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, animation, jquery-animate, sliding

I have created a portfolio image gallery but can't get the captions to work properly... I am using: http://s3.amazonaws.com/buildinternet/live-tutorials/sliding-boxes/index.htm (I'm using the second one)

The only problem is my captions are different sizes so I'm trying to use the code below:

```
$('.boxgrid.caption').hover(function () {
    var $height = $("#description-text", this).height();
    $(".cover", this).stop().animate({
        top: '375' - $height
    }, {
        queue: false,
        duration: 160
    });
}, function () {
    $(".cover", this).stop().animate({
        top: '365px'
    }, {
        queue: false,
        duration: 160
    });
});
```

But for some reason the output code of `$height` is 395 when it should be 150 or somewhere along those lines...

Please help...

Thanks
Ben

Comment: You really need to give more context, or provide a fiddle.  It's hard to understand what you are talking about when you are giving us selectors that seem to come out of no where.  What's "#description-text"?

Comment: Have you made sure your `description-text` div is actually height 150? I usually test by changing `style="background-color:Fuchsia;"` or another color to see how big the div actually is

Comment: visit http://jagdogweb.com under the portfolio tab

Answer (score 0):

`$("#description-text", this)` is rather odd.

`$("#description-text")` should suffice, that is provided you have only one element with this ID in your code. If not, well, then that will be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using outerHeight(), as it includes padding&border within the box

Answer (score 0):

Change the second line

```
var $height = $("#description-text").height();
```

Comment: But that only returns a value if the height is set in the CSS definition. The way I understand it, the height depends on the content of the element. So swenflea will be after the DOM height which requires him to use `.height()`

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the answer (sort of) I just changed the textbox to the side and I'm going to have it slide in from the side...

Thanks
Ben